# how to filter the key value object based on value substring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filtering

The below is the array of objects I have. This has objects with each date multiple times.

```
"list": [
        {
            "dt": 1545760800,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-25 18:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1545771600,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-25 21:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1545782400,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-26 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1545782400,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-26 03:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1545782400,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-26 04:00:00"
        }
       ]
```

How to filter this array of object to get only one object for each data. dt_txt

```
"list": [
        {
            "dt": 1545760800,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-25 18:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1545782400,
            "dt_txt": "2018-12-26 00:00:00"
        }
       ]
```

How to get this?

Comment: which dt_txt will be taken for same dt?

Comment: There will be no same dt. it is unique. It is the UNIX timestamp of the dt_txt.

Comment: You example data clearly shows multiple records with the same `dt` value. Please [edit] your question to include realistic inputs, outputs, and rules for how you got from the inputs to the outputs. It would be best to include an attempt you’ve made at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in different ways:

1] In the `accumulator` array check if an object with same date as `dt_txt` exists. If yes, skip the item, else add the item to the `accumulator`

```js
const list = [{"dt": 1545760800,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 18:00:00"},{"dt": 1545771600,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 21:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 00:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 03:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 04:00:00"}]

const filter1 = list.reduce((acc, i) => (
  acc.find(a => new Date(a.dt_txt).toDateString() === new Date(i.dt_txt).toDateString())
  ? '' 
  : acc.push(i), acc), 
[]);

console.log(filter1);
```

2] In the second approach, a separate function `compareDates` is created to compare the dates and return a `boolean`. I'm using [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) to compare the dates

```js
const list = [{"dt": 1545760800,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 18:00:00"},{"dt": 1545771600,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 21:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 00:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 03:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 04:00:00"}]

// create a seperate function to compare the dates a return a boolean
const compareDates = (d1, d2) => new Date(d1).toDateString() === new Date(d2).toDateString();

const filter2 = list.reduce((acc, i) => (
  acc.find(a => compareDates(a.dt_txt, i.dt_txt)) ? '' : acc.push(i), acc)
,[])

console.log(filter2);
```

3] In the third approach, the objective is to create an object with unique date values as key. For every item in the original array, check if that date already exists as a key in the `accumulator`. If yes, skip the current item in context, else add the current item as it's value. In the end you have a key-value pair of distinct objects in the orginal array. So, just get the values using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const list =[{"dt": 1545760800,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 18:00:00"},{"dt": 1545771600,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 21:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 00:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 03:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 04:00:00"}];

// gets only the date part in string 
const getDateString = (date) => new Date(date).toDateString();

const filter3 = Object.values(
      list.reduce((acc, i) => 
        (acc[getDateString(i.dt_txt)] = acc[getDateString(i.dt_txt)] || i, acc),{}))
        
console.log(filter3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're question asks for one item for each `data.dt_txt` but your desired result looks like you only want the first part of `data.dt_txt`. It should be clear that this will work either way — just don't split the value if you want the whole thing.

You can just keep a `set` of seen values and filtered based on that. If you find a new value add it to the set:

```js
let list = [{"dt": 1545760800,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 18:00:00"},{"dt": 1545771600,"dt_txt": "2018-12-25 21:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 00:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 03:00:00"},{"dt": 1545782400,"dt_txt": "2018-12-26 04:00:00"}]

let seen = new Set()
let filtered = list.filter(item => {
    let [date, _] = item.dt_txt.split(' ')
    return seen.has(date) ?  false : seen.add(date)
})

console.log(filtered)
```